# Size of character in pixels

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I am trying to create text box in the HTML5 canvas, I know you can't actually do this, so I am creating a box and creating some text at the same location. But, I want to make sure the text stays in the box so I need to know when part of the text is extending out of the box. I figure I should be able to measure the text in terms of pixels and then compare it to the box. My question is, using javascript, how can I measure the size of the characters for any given font?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use context.measureText to get the width of your specified text:

```
// set the font

context.font = "14px verdana";

// use measureText to get the text width

var textWidth = context.measureText("Measure this!").width;
```

Text wrap would look something like this:

```
function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, fontSizeFace) {
  var words = text.split(' ');
  var line = '';
  var lineHeight=measureTextHeight(fontSizeFace);

  for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
    var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
    var testWidth = metrics.width;
    if(testWidth > maxWidth) {
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      line = words[n] + ' ';
      y += lineHeight;
    }
    else {
      line = testLine;
    }
  }
  context.fillText(line, x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use as markE mention in his answer the `measureText()` function.

The [specifications defines](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#textmetrics) its result (a `TextMetrix`):

```
interface TextMetrics {
  // x-direction
  readonly attribute double width; // advance width
  readonly attribute double actualBoundingBoxLeft;
  readonly attribute double actualBoundingBoxRight;

  // y-direction
  readonly attribute double fontBoundingBoxAscent;
  readonly attribute double fontBoundingBoxDescent;
  readonly attribute double actualBoundingBoxAscent;
  readonly attribute double actualBoundingBoxDescent;
  readonly attribute double emHeightAscent;
  readonly attribute double emHeightDescent;
  readonly attribute double hangingBaseline;
  readonly attribute double alphabeticBaseline;
  readonly attribute double ideographicBaseline;
};
```

The problem however is that only `width` is implemented in the major browsers so you cannot get the height (ascent + descent) with this function yet (and I wouldn't be surprised if a canvas based word processor from at least one of the "major 3" shows up right before this gets fully implemented... but that's a regression and a speculation :-) ).

In order to measure the font you will have to use a DOM element, and this little trick will allow you to measure a font's width and height:

**[Online demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/4eMEW/)** (open console to see result).

```
function measureText(font, txt) {

    var el = document.createElement('div'),
        cs, res;

    el.style.cssText = 'position:fixed;left:-4000px;top:-4000px;padding:0;margin:0;font:' + font;
    el.innerHTML = txt;

    document.body.appendChild(el);

    cs = getComputedStyle(el);

    res = {width: cs.getPropertyValue('width'),
           height: cs.getPropertyValue('height')};

    document.body.removeChild(el);

    return res;    
}
```

The function creates a div element, applies some basic styles to it to place it outside window. This is because we have to attach it to the DOM tree in order to use `getComputedStyle()` - we also have to get the property values before we remove the element again.

Pass arguments for font as you would with the context (ie. `20px sans-serif`) and the text.

It comes with a small performance penalty obviously (though using fixed positioned elements won't cause any re-flow so it's not so bad) so use sparsely.